# Replacing String in Java

Tags: java, json, replace

I have something like this from converting an object to JSON:

```
String={"FirstName":"ABC","LastName":"XYZ",}
```

But I want the output to look like this:

```
{\"FirstName\":\"ABC\",\"LastName\":\"XYZ\"}
```

How can I achieve this using Java code? I tried using the `replace` function but I am unable to do it.

Comment: do you want to add escape character \" ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: yes or you can say replace " with \"

Comment: For me that looks like an XY question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378 since the real challenge here seems to convert/parse objects to json, not to escape a quote.

Comment: What exactly are you planning to do with the string? As S. Piller said, this sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Actually when I convert I from Java to Json I need the output with \ character

Comment: No you need a framework that knows how to convert an object to a json representation. Too many traps with manual serialisation (how do you handle this content: String value = "this is a quote: \"") ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you escape the special characters? It would look like this `replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"")`

Comment: Correct syntax is replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"") since you need to escape the backslash and quote once for java, and once for the regexp engine

Answer (score 0):

You should escape \ and " characters in Java. Hence to do what you want  you can try the following code: `string.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");`